# Thank you for reading *up* my letter

Tags: word-usage, american-english, phrasal-verbs

> Dear XXX
>
> AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
>
> BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
>
> CCCCCC. Thank you for reading **up** my letter.
>
> Best regards,
>
> Gqq Nbig

I want to emphasize that you finished reading letter instead of just reading a few sentences, so I used "[up](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/up_1?q=up)" as in "The stream has dried up." and "I have some paperwork to finish up." After all, when the reader reads this sentence, I assume they have finished reading the previous paragraphs.

But my spell checker marks the up wrong.

Is "reading **up** my letter" correct here?

Comment: No, you can't add ***up*** to ***read*** to indicate "completion". Which wouldn't be necessary anyway - why would you thank someone for reading your letter if they didn't even bother to read *all* of it? You can ***read up on** a topic or area of study*, which *tends* to suggest more ***in-depth study*** than simply reading ***about*** something, but even that one wouldn't put native speakers in mind of a "completed act" (reading *everything*).

Comment: In my opinion, "(verb) *up*" to indicate completion has a slightly childish or at least very informal feel.  Consider "They ate *up* all the food" vs "They ate all the food."

Comment: Up is used as a pointless filler word by many people - meet up, read up, first up etc.   Don't make yourself appear as ignorant as those people.

Comment: for reading the full letter, for reading the whole letter, for reading through the letter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This use is not idiomatic; your spellchecker is correct. There are a few ways to phrase this. But if you want to emphasize that you are glad they took the time to read it carefully, you would say: "Thank you for taking the time to read my letter."

Answer (score 4):

No, neither 7 nor 8 of Oxford's definitions applies here. [Read up](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/read-up) or **read up on** means to gather information about something by reading as much as you can.

Rather than thanking the recipient for finishing the letter, it's more usual to thank them for taking the trouble to read it.